# Poisson equation on half space

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> On the closed upper half space of ${\mathbb R}^{3}$ i.e.
>
> $\quad\forall\ x, y$, and $z\geq 0\quad$ find functions $\quad u, v\quad $ satisfying:
>
> $$\Delta u = 1\text{ and }u(x, 0)=0$$
>
> and
>
> $$\Delta v = \delta(0, 0, 1).$$

Comment: Your condition $z>0$ actually gives an open half space, not a closed half space. Could you also give some idea of where you are stuck with this problem.

Comment: Hi new user! $\color{red}{\Large\text{Welcome to Math.SE!}}$ Please show your working :)

Comment: Up to now we have only been working with Laplace equation (0 right hand side) which has a closed form solution. Adding the non-homogenous term on the right is throwing me off since my technique goes out the window. Thus I believe there should be an extension or I think we should be able to reformulate the problem with the right hand side being an initial condition of some sort.

Comment: It is absurd to vote to close questions like this as "off-topic".  It's just newbie-biting.

Comment: any hints?      not sure what to try next

Comment: I agree with @MichaelHardy .

Comment: What is $\delta\left(\,0,0,1\,\right)$ ?.

Answer (score 0):

Constant Laplacian corresponds to the function being a quadratic polynomial. (Indeed, the Laplacian of quadratic form $x\mapsto x^TAx$ is twice the trace of $A$). To satisfy the zero boundary condition, take $u$ to be a multiple of $z^2$.

As for $v$, just shift  the fundamental solution of $\Delta$ by one unit up. You'll get some multiple of $(x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2)^{-1/2}$.